# Testing function that returns gin.HandlerFunc

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a golang function that returns a `gin.HandlerFunc`:

```
func CheckLoggingServiceAccount(config *config) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        userId, _ := c.Get("userID")
        log.Info().Msgf("CheckLoggingServiceAccount invoked with userId %v, user %s", userId, userId.(string))
        allowedServiceAccountList := config.ServiceAccountsLogging

        serviceAccounts := strings.Split(allowedServiceAccountList, ",")
    
        if !util.Contains(serviceAccounts, userId.(string)) {
            log.Error().Msg(fmt.Sprintf("user %s is not allowed to perform this operation", userId))
            model.RespForbidden(c, fmt.Errorf("user %s is not allowed to perform this operation", userId))
            c.Abort()
            return
        }
        c.Next()
        return
    }
}
```

I've tried different ways of testing this but nothing works.  Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: _I've tried different ways of testing this_ [...]. Such as?

Comment: What do you want to test? That it returns a handler? The handler logic itself?